# socket.io properly disconnect a socket from unity side

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io

I am trying to properly close a socket of socket.io that got open from unity side. My problem is that, even though I expect one log information from unity side (server disconnected) and one in server side, I get my "bye" message, multiples of times, around 10 times, from server side (unity side publishes only 1 time, as expected). Could you please tell me how could I prevent this overhead, and why the repetition is happening?

On unity side, using a free scoket.io plugin, I have the code:

```
    void Start () {
     socket = GetComponent<SocketIOComponent> ();
     socket.On ("open", OnOpen);
     socket.On ("disconnect", OnDisconnect);
    }

    void OnDisconnect(SocketIOEvent e){
     Debug.Log ("server disconnected!");
     socket.Close ();
    }
```

in server side, my test code is:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('bye...');
socket.disconnect(true);
});
```

Comment: could you post a link to the exact plugin?

Comment: Yes, please:https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721

Comment: Ive used that asset before and I&#39;ve also had problems with repeated messages being sent to server when the client only does something once. I think it&#39;s a fault of the plugin as it&#39;s 3 years old and likely unsupported. If u still want to use it, try using a version of socket.io that was made around Sept 2014. If you want a up to date alternative (which you should) try using a  websockets library for C#

Comment: Brian, could you please suggest a C# lib or tutorial as a starting point? I need to manage a robust communication between unity and backend on nodejs but I don't know what to use? I'm thinking of using socket in nodeside and ...what in C# side please?